# How to run an interactive python script inside a shell script?

Tags: python, shell

I need to call a python tool (buttons.py), inside my shell script (emailsend.sh).  The tricky part is this python tool is written in interacive mode. This is how I manually trigger tool button.py:

`./button.py` (which put users in the screen interactive console, and on it, I need to type the following:)

```
>>> tsr()
>>> tl()  
>>> activate(355)
```

Is there a way to embed all that inside my emailsend.sh script?

Comment: if the python script is not too long, upload it here, and you will be better helped.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
./button.py << EOF
tsr()
tl()
activate(355)
EOF
```